# Run Asyntask code when Application is closed or in background

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-notifications

I have this class:

```
private class ReadRSSTask extends AsyncTask < URL, Integer[], Integer[] > {

    protected Integer[] doInBackground(URL...urls) {
        try {
            feed = RssReader.read(urls[0]);
            rssItems = feed.getRssItems();
            for (RssItem rssItem: rssItems) {
                item = new Item(rssItem.getTitle(), rssItem.getDescription(),
                        rssItem.getPubDate());
                list.add(item);
            }
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        size = list.size();
        ...
        return new Integer[]{size,size_};
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer[] result) {
        final int how = (copySize-result[0])*-1;
        final int how_ = (copySize_-result[1])*-1;
        if (how > 0) {
            avvisi.setText(String.valueOf(how));
        }
        if (how_ > 0) {
            eventi.setText(String.valueOf(how_));
        }
    }
}
```

I wish this method run even when the app is closed or in background and display the notification.
It must check if the app is in the background or is closed and call them the method, right?

Comment: you are looking for a service not asynctask

Comment: I agree with Raghunandan. 
But if you want to display notification like Toast. Better not using `avvisi.setText` or similar views. 'cos that view is not there anymore

Comment: You need a service. If you want the service to be executed independently, you'll need something like an alarm trigger.

Answer (score 0):

When you want some code to be executed while no `Activity` is shown to the user, you should use a class derived from the `Service` class. Notice that a `Service` itself can execute using its own thread.